# getting javax.servlet.ServletException: when running my eclipse on jboss?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I am getting javax.servlet.ServletException: when running my web application on jboss. I am not getting want to do. need help. below is the log;

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load application class: com.example.tutorials.TutorialsApplication
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.init(ApplicationServlet.java:71)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what do you have in WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the class `ApplicationServlet` "fails to load the class" `com.example.tutorials.TutorialsApplication`. And this class is called "Application". This is (probably) not a jboss/webapp error, but an error associated with the Vaadin framework.

Is the "missing" class available on the classpath (in your war)? In your project?

Why does `ApplicationServlet` try to load the class? Is there some configuration pointing to this class (maybe in web.xml)? Have you renamed the class but not updated the config?

Maybe not an answer to your question, but some troubleshooting tips...